# Как правильно делать AJAX запросы?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

Всем привет. Необходимо сделать два параллельных fetch запроса на сервер с обработкой ошибок каждого, пытаюсь понять стоит ли это делать через Promise.all()/Promise.allSettled() или можно просто друг за другом написать:

```
         fetch(url1)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {

                },

                (error) => {

                }
            )

        fetch(url2)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {

                },

                (error) => {

                }
            )
```

Comment: Если вам нужен именно Promise.all — делайте, не нужен — не делайте

Comment: Promise.all будет ждать результат каждого промиса и только потом вернет вам ответы всех промисов массивом, если вы хотите ловить ошибки на лету, то не используйте .all

Comment: Мне нужно отлавливать ошибки каждого запроса, и при этом сделать запросы параллельными. Единственное решение, что мне пришло в голову, так это добавить каждый запрос(запросы такие, как в вопросе. выше) в массив и передать его в Promise.all. Но мне кажется это не очень правильное решение и есть какие то общеизвестные практики для этого.